# How to get predictions MLP tensorflow from a restored model?

Tags: r, tensorflow

stackoverflowers , I need some help from tensorflow experts. Actually I've buid a multi-layer perceptron, trained it, tested it and everything seemed ok. However, When I restored the model and tried to use it again, its accuracy does not correspond to the trained model and the predictions are pretty different from the real labels. The code I am using for the restoring - prediction is the following : (I'm using R)

```
pred <- multiLayerPerceptron(test_data)
init <- tf$global_variables_initializer()
with(tf$Session() %as% sess, {
  sess$run(init)
  model_saver$restore(sess, "log_files/model_MLP1")
  test_pred_1 <- sess$run(pred, feed_dict= dict(x =  test_data))

})
```

Is everything Ok with the code ? FYI I wanted by this part of the code to get the predictions of my model for test_data.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using the same data on your model, or a different "test" dataset?

Comment: I am using an other set as " training_data" but the same kind of data of course. The problem is that the accuracy of the model on this test set too is good when I assess under the same session just after the training, but once I close everything and I try to restore the model, I have the feeling that it is acting like a randomly generated NN not trained at all. Thus, I think the problem is in the restoration syntax.

Comment: So it works great on your training set but once it gets into the "real world", it doesn't work well. Sounds like a case of overfitting.

Comment: You didn't get my point. Under the same session , when I train the model and finish training and before closing the session I test on the test data, both training accuracy and test accuracy are good. But Once I want to restore the model, it doesn't work anymore neither on training data nor on the test data. It acts as I've said before ' Like a NN with randomly generated weights '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not show where `model_saver` is initialized, but it should be created after you create the computational graph. If not, it does not know which variables to restore/save. So create your `model_saver` after `pred <- multiLayerPerceptron(test_data)`.

Note that, if you made the same mistake during training, your checkpoint will be empty and you will need to retrain your model first.